# How does the Dev.to website wrap their post cards inside a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Example of a post card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvB6v.png)

I know they use an absolutely positioned link tag one level below the root element and sized it to fill the width and height of the card. But I can't figure out how you can still click on individual links without the full size link blocking it.

```
<article>
  <a id="full sized link"></a>
  <div id="actual content">
    <h3>
      <a id="individual link">TITLE</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
</article>
```

Here is roughly how the cards are structured.

I think them may be using JavaScript to redirect you.

Comment: The full sized link has `pointer-events: none` that's how clicks can pass right through it, it's not there for clicks or taps, it's there for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the anchor tag you want to target to set

```
 <a id="full-sized-link" href='#' ></a>

#full-sized-link{
    height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    article{
    position:relative;
    }
```

And on individual links higher z-index

```
#individual-link{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```